# Regex to strip all numbers and special characters but space and letters

Tags: python, regex

Can someone help me out with the regular expression to strip a string like this ->

```
      '226710': 'Kevin Werbach'
```

to obtain just -->  Kevin Werbach

My attempt -->

```
   instructors = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z\s]+?)', '', instructors)
```

which returned -->

```
  KevinWerbach
```

without any space between.

Comment: Strip or capture? If capture maybe `'([a-zA-Z ]+?)'`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it would help to have some more context regarding your input. For example, do you want to remove the first part of the line only when there are numbers within the apostrophes, or do you want to do the same if there are letters too? What are some examples of lines that you don't want to modify?

Comment: From the example, I want to retain just --> Kevin Werbach

Comment: My attempt -->      re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z ]+?)'   which returned KevinWerbach without any space.

Comment: yes it removed the white space too and i am using this in python

Comment: Okay, I've added the python tag. I'm unfamiliar with python, it is strange that it would continue capturing and ignore a part, could that be a tab or a non standard space?

Comment: It is a non-standard space @chris85

Comment: `re.sub()` requires 3 arguments. What is `re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z ]+?)'` supposed to mean? What did you replace it with?

Comment: instructors = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z\s]+?)', '', instructors)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
import re
text = "'226710': 'Kevin Werbach'"
print(re.sub (r'([^a-zA-Z ]+?)', '', text))
```

You can also change the space to \s:

```
print(re.sub (r'([^a-zA-Z\s]+?)', '', text))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can you select this as the answer?